# How to remove the month name from CalendarView header

Tags: android, calendarview

I want to remove the header with the month name, I want to display only the dates, how can I remove this from calendarView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well try this [Calendar](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview/blob/master/docs/CUSTOMIZATION.md#topbar-options).

It provides a lot of customization.

Answer (score 2):

Didn't try it, but it might work:

```
CalendarView cv = (CalendarView) this.findViewById(R.id.calendarView1);
ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) cv.getChildAt(0);

View subView = vg.getChildAt(0);

if(subView instanceof TextView) {
  ((TextView)subView).setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: View at ```getChildAt(0)``` is the ```DayPickerView``` and it is the only child view.